# Upper limit on simultaneous streaming from a single AppleTV+ subscription?

Tags: appletv

Is there an officially enforced limit on the maximum number of screens that can simultaneously stream from a single AppleTV+ subscription?

While a single AppleTV+ subscription can be shared by a family of six using Apple's Family Sharing, I am looking to determine the limit enforced (if any) on a single Apple ID.

Comment: Why would you presume there’s a hard limit? In the past, Apple starts very lenient - sees what people does, remediate / investigate / check in with cases where the usage is far higher than the norm. The license is going to be clear, but the programming doesn’t necessarily have to follow.

Comment: @bmike Generally streaming services enforce some kind of upper limit to curtail the abuse of the system.

Comment: Generally, Apple doesn’t try to follow other services down the same implementation plan or architecture or design.

Comment: @bmike I agree with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Apple Support document [Download and stream shows and movies from Apple TV+ and Apple TV channels](https://support.apple.com/HT210074), 6 streams at the same time are the limit for the normal subscription:

> Apple TV+: One subscription allows you to enjoy 6 simultaneous streams.

Since they say, that 6 streams are allowed, multiple streams per Account should be possible. Otherwise they would state, that up to 6 Accounts could be linked to the subscription.

But restrictions apply to students with the cheaper subscription:

> If you have an Apple Music student subscription, which includes Apple TV+ for a limited time, you can only stream Apple TV+ on one device at a time.

Comment: Can you share the link to the support article you quoted from?

Comment: @NimeshNeema The „support-site“ is a hyperlink. You can now also find the url at the bottom of my answer.